# Use of current toolchain in bazel rule

Tags: static-libraries, bazel, bazel-rules

I've use the below bazel rule to build static libraries with bazel:

```
def _cc_static_library_impl(ctx):
    cc_deps = [dep[CcInfo] for dep in ctx.attr.deps]
    libraries = []
    for cc_dep in cc_deps:
        for link_input in cc_dep.linking_context.linker_inputs.to_list():
            for library in link_input.libraries:
                libraries += library.pic_objects
    args = ["r", ctx.outputs.out.path] + [f.path for f in libraries]
    ctx.actions.run(
        inputs = libraries,
        outputs = [ctx.outputs.out],
        executable = "/usr/bin/ar",
        arguments = args,
    )
    return [DefaultInfo()]

cc_static_library = rule(
    implementation = _cc_static_library_impl,
    attrs = {
        "deps": attr.label_list(providers = [CcInfo]),
    },
    outputs = {"out": "lib%{name}.a"},
)
```

How can I extract the command to use from the current toolchain instead of using the hardcoded `/usr/bin/ar`? I've based the rule on what I've found on the internet and I have very limited knowledge about this. This example seems to do something related:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/main/examples/my_c_archive/my_c_archive.bzl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the relevant part of `my_c_archive`:

```py
    archiver_path = cc_common.get_tool_for_action(
        feature_configuration = feature_configuration,
        action_name = CPP_LINK_STATIC_LIBRARY_ACTION_NAME,
    )
```

That gets you the path, and then you need to add `cc_toolchain.all_files` to your `ctx.actions.run` call, so it ends up looking like this:

```py
    ctx.actions.run(
        inputs = depset(
            direct = [libraries],
            transitive = [
                cc_toolchain.all_files,
            ],
        ),
        outputs = [ctx.outputs.out],
        executable = archiver_path,
        arguments = args,
    )
```

However, you'll also notice that `my_c_archive` builds up a command line and environment variables to call the archiver with. A simple toolchain won't have anything to pass in either of those, but a more complex one may not work correctly without adding them (for example, passing `-m32` or setting `PATH`).

Part of the starlark implementation of `cc_import` in [`_create_archive_action` in cc_import.bzl](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/cf010cc2488ce71a9495aacf187c84388e7a0d01/tools/build_defs/cc/cc_import.bzl#L75) is a good place to start for handling all the intricacies. It creates an action to produce a static library from a set of object files, with flexibility to work with many toolchains.